# What is the proper way to manipulate arrays using values from a select list?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with 2 inputs which are both select lists. For each value selected, I want the code to select a specific value from the array but for some reason, the same value (which) is the first value of the array is selected. Kindly help. Here is the code:

```
    <?php
       $notentrained = array(0.38, 0.42, 0.47, 0.54, 0.61, 0.69, 0.79);
       $entrained = array(0.30, 0.34, 0.39, 0.45, 0.52, 0.60, 0.70);
       if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
         $compressiveStrength = $_GET['compressiveStrength'];
         if (isset($_GET['concreteSpecification'])) {
             $concreteSpecification = $_GET['concreteSpecification'];
         }

        if ($compressiveStrength = 45 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
            echo $notentrained [0];
        }       elseif ($compressiveStrength = 40 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
                    echo  $notentrained [1];
                }elseif ($compressiveStrength = 35 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
                    echo  $notentrained [2];
                }elseif ($compressiveStrength = 30 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
                        echo  $notentrained [3];
                }elseif ($compressiveStrength = 25 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
                    echo  $notentrained [4];
                }elseif ($compressiveStrength = 20 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
                    echo  $notentrained [5];
                }elseif ($compressiveStrength = 15 && $concreteSpecification = 1) {
                    echo  $notentrained [6];
                } 

      }


   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Common mistakes, I think : `=` or `==`?

```php
if ($compressiveStrength == 45 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
    echo $notentrained [0];
}       elseif ($compressiveStrength == 40 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
            echo  $notentrained [1];
        }elseif ($compressiveStrength == 35 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
            echo  $notentrained [2];
        }elseif ($compressiveStrength == 30 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
                echo  $notentrained [3];
        }elseif ($compressiveStrength == 25 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
            echo  $notentrained [4];
        }elseif ($compressiveStrength == 20 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
            echo  $notentrained [5];
        }elseif ($compressiveStrength == 15 && $concreteSpecification == 1) {
            echo  $notentrained [6];
        } 

}
```